# Create Android Actionbar Menu like Play Music

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction for creating a menu for my app that uses a button on the action bar.

I want this menu to be similar to the Play Music app, the Gmail app, and the Feedly app.

an example of this can be found here:

[image: http://i39.tinypic.com/2jb4g2h.png]

Comment: You might consider posting a screenshot somewhere and use that to explain *precisely* what you mean by "similar to the Play Music app, the GMail app and the feedly app". Those applications are very complex, with many different activities and fragments, and therefore the action bar has many different looks within those applications. Plus, not everybody uses the applications you listed and therefore may not know what they look like.

Comment: I did say the menu from those apps. the applications may be complex but as far as im aware the gmail app and music app only have one main menu.

i tried to provide a screenshot but it wouldnt let me so ive edited now and just provided a direct URL.

Comment: I did also expect to find something about this on the developer documentation as it seems to be common in most of googles own android apps now but i couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1):

> I did say the menu from those apps

And since what you are referring to isn't a menu, this is why screenshots are important.

> the applications may be complex but as far as im aware the gmail app and music app only have one main menu

That's not a menu. That is a [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). The current Android Support package has [`DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) for this, and there are various third-party implementations available as well.

Comment: Thanks you very much. i assumed it was a menu because it looks and acts like one. i wasnt trying to be cocky i just assumed it was a menu. thanks again!

Comment: @dtothef: Part of the confusion was that "menu" has a specific meaning in Android (referring to old-timey options and context menus).

Comment: No problem. i guess it was my lack of understanding what it was named. thanks for clearing this up though!